# How do I use functions of the MVC in a page loaded by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

My controller looks something like this:

```
jQuery.extend({
    Controller: function(model, view){

    //-----VIEW-----//
    var vlist = $.ViewListener({
        clickItem : function(Item){
            switch (Item) {
                case 'File':
                    //do something
                    break;
                default:
                    //do something else
            }
        }
    });
    view.addListener(vlist);

    //-----MODEL-----//
    var mlist = $.ModelListener({
        gotContent : function(Item) {
            switch (Item.type) {
                case 'Download':
                    //do someting else
                    break;
                default:
                    //do something else
            }
            //update view
        }
    });
    model.addListener(mlist);

    }
});
```

How do I use the clickItem function from a page that was not created by the MVC?

I have tried view.clickItem and many other ways however nothing is defined because it is all in private functions.

I load the MVC like this:

```
$(function(){
    var model = new $.Model();
    var view = new $.View($("#framework"));
    var controller = new $.Controller(model, view);
    view.init();
});
```

Basically I have link that I would like to act the same way as the clickItem function.

Comment: Should probably clarify that the MVC does fetch the page just not create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get around this by using jQuery's .live() method.
On the ajax success callback I ran a jQuery .live() method to attach an onclick event to the element that calls the clickItem() function.